# each_connected in wp_user_query with Scribu's Posts to Posts Plugin - Alternative method?

Tags: wp-user-query, plugin-posts-to-posts

I have been using Scribu's Posts to Posts plugin for some time, and it has served me well. I have read the full wiki and issues list, but can't find any definitive answer if there is a clean way to loop through many users while getting `each_connected`.

According to [this wiki entry](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected), the faster way to get connections inside a loop, is to use `each_connected`, to avoid having a second query inside each and every iteration of the loop. Makes sense, and works great for `posts` of varying types. But despite the similarities between `wp_query` and `wp_user_query`, this kind of thing doesn't work (but would work if we were in a `wp_query` instead):

```
$players = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
p2p_type( 'player_report_to_user' )->each_connected( $players );
```

If I run this kind of connection *inside* the `foreach($players as $player)` ...

```
$reports = get_posts( array(
    'connected_type' => 'player_report_to_user',
    'connected_items' => $player->ID,
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'nopaging' => true
) );
```

It absolutely works, but is very inefficient, as I have over 200 users being processed.

---

So, the question is: does anyone know of a method for applying `each_connected()` to a `wp_user_query()` so that I'm not making hundreds of extra queries?

### Update:

It seems the answer is "No." according to this: https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/issues/374 -
So might there be a way to write the SQL myself? I'm pretty shaky at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible without modifications to the p2p plugin, as indicated here:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/issues/374

Relevant code is here:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/blob/master/core/connection-type.php#L374

Comment: lol... spoonfed :)